# What does this python function do?

Tags: python, math

```
def f(b, n):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    def _f(n):
        if n == 0: return 1
        else: return b ** _f(n-1)
    return _f(n)
```

Taking a python class and we have to explain what this does so that a high school algebra student would understand. I am lost. I would appreciate if someone could push me in the right direction without giving me the answer.

Comment: What part in particular is posing problems?

Comment: What might help is if you were to write out the outcomes of calling the function on a sheet of paper, so you can track the state of the variables.  So assign values to b and n, and then walk it through the recursive calls.

Comment: I guess its more of a math problem. I cant wrap my head around what is going on in order to explain it, I don't consider myself to have a strong math background.

Comment: ok maybe if I understood exactly what the second line is doing I could grasp it better.

Comment: @bizarrechaos `assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0` asserts (ie makes sure) that n is an integer and that its value is >= 0.

Comment: function f accepts b and and int n. And _f acts as a loop and for lack of better words increases b exponentially until n is 0. Am I close?

Comment: So in essence n is the number of times b is exponentially increased. how do I explain the last b^0...

Comment: not answering the question, but this is a poor use of assert (it should be a `raise` here instead)

Comment: @wim I was given the function by my professor. Could you explain why a raise would be better than an assert?

Comment: Raise an exception for unexpected behaviour, use an assert to sanity check your code for something that should NEVER happen. You would usually remove/disable asserts when deploying your code.

Comment: @bizarrechaos msanders is correct.  assert shouldn't be used for validating input, as appears to be the use case here.  it's rather a safeguard for checking the programmer's logic, to help catch any bugs that the programmer might have made by erroneous assumptions.  for example, if you were implementing a sorting algorithm in a function you might assert that the output IS sorted right before returning it.

Comment: Did you **try it**? Did you try looking for a pattern in the results?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes I did for quite sometime. I've completed the problem so everyone can stop downvoting now. This will probably be the last time I ask for help on here...people ask to learn not be ridiculed and downvoted because it was a "stupid question". Thank you to all who helped or at least tried, I would upvote your suggestions but I lost that privilege because I asked this question.

Comment: BTW, this function has a name: [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function computes `b` raised to the power of itself raised to the power of itself `n-1` times where `n` is at least `1`. It's equivalent to this simpler non-recursive function:

```
def g(b, n):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    ret = 1
    for _ in xrange(n):
        ret = b ** ret
    return ret
```

It would look something like this written as a mathematical formula:

[image: math formula of function]

Comment: Thanks for writing that out in a way that suggests you aren't trying to confuse newcomers by returning functions, instead of values. OP, here's your answer. Please link this to your teacher while you're at it, too.

Comment: @Droogans: Thanks, but I doubt the OP will change their answer at this point. The main reason posted mine was because I thought it was clearer than any of the others I had seen. BTW, the original code _is_ returning a non-function value, it's the value of the result of calling the currently defined local function which is recursive which makes it somewhat difficult to comprehend -- especially since there's really no reason for it and one of the values it uses, `b`, isn't even passed to it as a normal argument.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It's seemed the code defined a [decorator](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)</strike> . The inner definition of the **_fn** is for easy of the recursion. The code is calculating the following

```
b^(b^(b^(... (b^(b^0)))...))
```

i.e., given

```
b = 2
n = 3
```

the value will be:

```
16 = 2^(2^(2^(2^0)
```

Comment: Many thanks DSM. You're right. It's not a decorator. Updated.

Comment: f(2, 3) returns 16. 2^(2^(2^(2^0) is 16. So your example is wrong but your explanation is helping.

Comment: However f(2, 4) returns 65536 but is 2^(2^(2^(2^(2^0)

Answer (score 2):

> Taking a python class and we have to explain what this does so that a
>   high school algebra student would understand

function *f* takes two integers *b* and *n*. It raises the first one *b* to the power of the second one *n*, and reduces *n* by 1. This is repeated until *n* is zero, and the cumulative result is returned.

This doesn't answer any Python related questions like 'what does `assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0` do', and that I leave as exercise for the OP.